# compilation-scroll-output doesn't work if *compilation* buffer is created by hand

Tags: compilation, compile-mode

Emacs version 25

I have a short piece of elisp to create a few buffers and split my frame into multiple windows that are displayed the way I like. This code creates a `*compilation*` buffer and dedicates it using this code:

```
;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151620/how-do-i-make-this-emacs-frame-keep-its-buffer-and-not-get-resized
;; Toggle window dedication
(defun toggle-window-dedicated ()
  "Toggle whether the current active window is dedicated or not"
  (interactive)
  (message
   (if (let (window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
         (set-window-dedicated-p window
                                 (not (window-dedicated-p window))))
       "Window '%s' is dedicated"
     "Window '%s' is normal")
   (current-buffer)))

(switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*compilation*"))
(toggle-window-dedicated)
```

My issue is that when running a compilation, even if the compiler output goes to the correct buffer, the `*compilation*` buffer doesn't scroll automatically to always display the most recent text.

My configuration is `(setq compilation-scroll-output 'first-error)`

The normal scrolling behavior seems to only be enabled when the `*compilation*` buffer is created by the `compile` command and not by hand. Even if I make the window with this buffer dedicated latter.

Is there a correct way to create the `*compilation*` buffer without running the `compile` command but keeping the `compilation-scroll-output` configuration behavior?

EDIT: a more detailed procedure:

How to trigger the problem:

- put `mybuffer.el` and `Makefile` in one directory (`/tmp/emacs_problem` for example)
- open file `mybuffer.el`
- go to end of the `create-my-buffers` function and execute the code (C-x C-e)
- execute the `create-my-buffers` function with `M-x create-my-buffers`
- execute `M-x compile RET RET`

How to see the expected behavior:

- open file `mybuffer.el`
- execute `M-x compile RET RET`

The Makefile:

```
default:
    ls -1 /bin
```

mybuffer.el:

```
(defun create-my-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)

  (setq total-window-size (window-width (frame-selected-window)))
  (setq total-window-height (window-height (frame-selected-window)))

  (split-window-vertically)
  (other-window 1)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*compilation*"))
  (setq second-window-height (window-height (frame-selected-window)))
  (setq expected-window-height (* 0.10 total-window-height))
  (setq expand-window-height (- expected-window-height second-window-height))
  (enlarge-window (round expand-window-height))
  (other-window 1)
)
```

The result with the "bad" behavior, the window with the compilation buffer has not scrolled to the bottom:
[image: The result with the "bad" behavior, the window with the compilation buffer has not scrolled to the bottom]

The result with the good behavior, the cursor is at the end of the content and the window has scrolled correctly:
[image: The result with the good behavior, the cursor is at the end of the content and the window has scrolled correctly]

The output for `M-x describe-mode` after calling `M-x compile` is:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Autopair-Global Column-Number Company Company-Quickhelp
Company-Quickhelp-Local Delete-Selection Display-Time Electric-Indent
Evil-Matchit File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Auto-Revert
Global-Company Global-Eldoc Global-Evil-Matchit Global-Font-Lock
Global-Git-Gutter Global-Linum Global-Undo-Tree Global-Visual-Line
Global-Whitespace Hl-Line Line-Number Mouse-Wheel Save-Place
Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree Visual-Line

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Compilation mode defined in ‘compile.el’:
Major mode for compilation log buffers.
To visit the source for a line-numbered error,
move point to the error message line and type RET.
To kill the compilation, type C-c C-k.

Runs ‘compilation-mode-hook’ with ‘run-mode-hooks’ (which see).
```

EDIT 2: It seems that the scrolling is done correctly if I launch `M-x compile` from the window containing `*compilation*` rather than from the window containing `mybuffer.el`.

Comment: Just creating a buffer named \*compilation\* won't work. You also have to enable some *compilation mode*. Not at my computer, so couldn't help more.

Comment: The problem is here even if I set the compilation mode using `(compilation-mode)` just after the `switch-to-buffer`.

Also, the compilation mode will be set automatically if I don't set it by hand when I launch the first compilation.

I took screenshots of the two buffers: https://imgur.com/gallery/muHuu

Comment: I don't follow. Can you provide a full recipe to recreate your problem? Currently you just have code about toggling dedicated window and creating the \*compilation\* buffer. You'll need to enlist the full steps for anyone to recreate the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Nitpick: you say "the \*compilation\* buffer doesn't scroll", but in reality, buffers don't scroll, windows do.  I believe this difference is key to understanding your problem.  As Klaushal says, you don't provide enough info to solve your problem, but I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `M-x compile` doesn't setup the window you're using (maybe it sets up another window which displays the same buffer?).

Comment: Ok I tried to put everything needed in this gist. Please let me know if anything is missing. https://gist.github.com/Khady/d569687312e4950f86b0335e81ac60c0

Answer (score 0):

revision:

Since I wasn't able to recreate my former success (see the comments below), the only answer I can offer is that the output scrolling works only in two cases: either, if you run the compilation command from the compilation buffer, or, if you re-use the compilation buffer for a second compilation.

It is not clear to me why any setup with `(compilation-mode "Compilation")` or `(compilation-setup)` does not work; it seems to ignore any customized variables when the `compile` command does not create the buffer itself.  Maybe this can be considered a bug and should be put into the Emacs bug tracker at gnu.org, if it is not already there.  The instance when I was able to make it work must have been a lucky shot, but, as already said, I cannot recreate what I did manually –– sorry.

Comment: Except that:

1. If I set the mode using `(compilation-mode)` just after the `switch-to-buffer` line, the result is the same.
2. The compilation mode is set automatically by `M-x compile` on the `*compilation*` buffer. You can see on the screenshot that the major mode is the good one because of `Compilation:exit [0]` IIUC.

Comment: hmm… are you sure that it is the fully-fledged mode and not simply a mode title update?

Comment: When I run `M-x describe-mode` on my `*compilation*` buffer after `M-x compile`, I think it tells that I'm using a compilation mode. But I don't know if it is the correct one. I added the output of `describe-mode` to the original question.

Comment: Just played around a bit with this again and found something in compile.el.  Insert `(compilation-setup t)` right after the buffer creation.  Then it works.

Comment: I don't manage to get it work. When you say right after the buffer creation, you mean after the `switch-to-buffer` line?

Comment: exactly.  That's where I put it, evaluated the defun and had the window scrolling.  But I killed the old *compilation* buffer first to have the genuine result.

Comment: I really don't manage to get it work. I discovered something new tho. I have the good behavior if I call `M-x compile` from the window containing the `*compilation*` buffer rather than the one containing the `mybuffer.el`.

Comment: does `(require 'compile)` at the top of the file help?

Comment: No, same behavior.

Comment: Sorry, Louis, I cannot help you here –– see my updated answer.  If anyone finds a solution, I'd be very interested in how he did it.